# Subdomain tracking with Google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

In order to separate statistics from devices with different form-factors I'd like to incorporate subdomain tracking - is there any relevant feature on Android GA SDK ?

P.S. If I'm not mistaken this feature is accessed with setDomainName method in JS API consumer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just utilize Advanced Segments in Google Analytics which will keep everything in the same profile, but will let you use segmentation to filter the data you want in reports?

For example, you can create a segment to filter all user agents of a certain string:

`INCLUDE` `BROWSER` `MATCHING REGEXP` `^(Your_custom_user_agent)$`

Comment: the thing is that I don't need to differentiate between user agents, but types of device configurations. For instance, I need to save statistic regarding handset/tablet distinction. I guess, I need to send some specific data(tablet=true or tablet=false). Any recommendations ?

Comment: So you're just wanting to determine what type/size of device is viewing the webpage?

Comment: yep, in the application I can specify a type(handset,tablet). The app consists of a bunch of pages(activities) which are accessed by different device types, so I need to send data to GA regarding the device type. That's why I was aked to implement subside management

Comment: Google Analytics is set up to detect device type, resolution, etc. by default. Read up on the docs here https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_medium=BrowserOS&utm_campaign=helpwidget&utm_source=visitors&answer=1144432 and here https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_medium=Mobile&utm_campaign=helpwidget&utm_source=visitors&answer=1011360

Comment: @AdamD  Can you give a code example in Java to do the Advanced Segment?  I have been unable to set it up thus far...